# Can I change a Product Attribute Property of an existing attribute without removing the associated simple products from configurable products?

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute, simple-product

I wish to change the "Add to Column Options" and "Use in Filter Options" properties in the Advanced Attribute Properties section of an existing Attribute that is used by all the products on our site.

However, when I try this locally all the simple products are no longer associated with their Configurable parents. Is this normal/expected? Is there a way round it?

From research it appears that adding or removing an entire attribute can have this affect, but I was hoping that I could change the property of an existing attribute without this happening.

I'm using Magento 2.1.3